# BlackJack - class solution incorrect?

Tags: python

Im working through a blackjack game as an assignment for a python course I purchased on udemy and I believe I've found an issue with the class's provided solution.  I made a change to the code myself to make it work, but I'd like to ask the stackoverflow community 2 questions:  1) Will someone please explain exactly why the solution doesn't work?  I will make a few guesses below but as a beginner I'd like to understand exactly whats wrong for my own benefit.  2) Is the way I fixed the problem a good solution?  If not, what are some other ways I could code this?

This is the given solution (I'm only showing the 3 classes of: Card, Hand and Deck - problem is within Deck, specifically Deck's **str** function)

```
# Let's start with defining our suits, ranks and values
suits = ('H','D','C','S')
ranking = ('A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K')
card_val = {'A':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}

class Card(object):
    # card needs a suit and rank
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.suit + self.rank

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def draw(self):
        print (self.suit + self.rank)

class Hand(object):
    # A hand needs 2 cards and a total value
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
        self.value = 0
        self.ace = False

    def __str__(self):
        hand_comp = ''
        for card in self.hand:
            card_name = card.__str__
            hand_comp += " " + card_name
        return 'The hand has %s' %hand_comp

    def card_add(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)

    # Check for Aces
    if card.rank == 'A':
        self.ace = True
    self.value += card_val[card.rank]

    def calc_val(self):
    # calculate the value of the hand, make aces an 11 if they don't bust
        if(self.ace == True and self.value < 12):
            return self.value + 10
        else:
            return self.value

    def draw(self, hidden):
        if hidden == True and  playing == True:
            #Don't show first hidden card
            starting_card = 1
        else:
            starting_card = 0
        for x in range(starting_card, len(self.hand)):
            self.hand[x].draw()


    class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for s in suits:
            for r in ranking:
                self.deck.append(Card(s,r))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ''
        for card in self.hand:
            deck_comp += " " + deck_comp.__str__()
        return "The deck has " + deck_comp
```

My problem is with the def **str** function under class Deck.  The solution asks the program to run a for loop over... self.hand (which is under class Hand).  I don't see why this would work at all.  self.hand doesn't have anything to do with getting a full deck returned to me.  Secondly, is deck_comp += " " + deck_comp.**str**() good code?  I find my program freezes up if I only changed the loop to self.deck.  I created a new variable called cards_name and assign it to cards.**str**() to get each card's suit and rank instead.

this is what I corrected the code to:

```
    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ''
        for card in self.deck:
            cards_name = card.__str__()
            deck_comp += " " + cards_name
        return "The deck has " + deck_comp
```

Comment: Yes, your change looks good to me. You don't need a card_name variable, though, you could append card.str() directly. But why ask us if you think it's wrong - why not ask on the class forums?

Comment: i did, no response to my question yet.  however, I did find a few similar questions asked but it was either not responded to or shut down by the instructor by him saying "I'm not sure quite what you are asking here? I believe the .cards attribute is described in the __init__ method"

Comment: Don't use `card.__str__()`, use `str(card)`